# Render a dictionary with object list as values in django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I have a dictionary new:

```
new = {'Delhi-Mumbai': [<Truckdb: Truckdb object (6)>], 'Doon-Gurgaon': [<Truckdb: Truckdb object (8)>, <Truckdb: Truckdb object (6)>]}
```

I am not able to render the objects from TruckDb in templates

this is what i tried in views.py

```
return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/dispatcher_output.html',{'res':new})
```

this is my template:

```
{% for k,v in res.items %}

      <h1>v value  is </h1>
      {{ v.Name }}

{% endfor %}
```

Models.py

```
class Truckdb(models.Model):

    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Truckid = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    Length = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Breadth = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Height = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Volume = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Weight = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong ?

### Edit

This is my output if use this in the template:

[image: des]

```
{% for k,v in res.items %}

        <h1>v value  is </h1>
        {{ v.Name }}

{% endfor %}
```

### What I want

I want to be able to use the objects just like any other model and get values based on the other properties the model has. Like so:

{% for k,v in res.items %}

```
        <h1>v value  is </h1>
        {{ v.Name }}
        {{ v.Category }}
        {{ v.Truckid }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Once again, your values are *lists*. You know how to iterate a list. Why can't you do that for each value?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am sorry but I am very new to django and not able to figure it out

Comment: @Alasdair updated the question

Comment: This is not a question about Django. If you can use a for loop, you already know how to answer this question.

Comment: Show us the code where you create the `new` variable because the the template code is correct so there must be an issue with `new`

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi - The output shows that there isn't a problem with the `new` variable and the template code *isn't* correct. The op needs to iterate over the values as explained above

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I am creating the `new` variable using another custom code which utilizes `pyshipping`. It will be a long task to show you how I got that code, but rest assured it is giving me that dictionary is correct. I can show how I am assigning the objects though  `for k, v in res.items():
        try:
            v = get_object_or_404(Truckdb, id=v)
            new[k] = v
        except :
            v = [get_object_or_404(Truckdb, id=v_id) for v_id in v]
            new[k] = v
            print(v)`

Comment: @RohitKumar Ok I see. At least show a sample of `new` using `print`

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am going to find the answer on my own and refrain from asking simple questions on SO.

Comment: @DanielRoseman check my answer

Comment: Your code to generate `new` is fragile. If the first `new[k] = v` in the `try` block succeeds, then `v` will be a single item. But in the `except` block, you do `new[k] = v` when `v` is a list. You should make sure that `v` is *always* a list or a single item, otherwise you'll hit other issues. It looks as if `v` might always be a list, in which case you should get rid of the code in the `try` block and just use the `except` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use two `for loops` because each element in the dict is a queryset

```
{% for k,v in res.items %}
    {% for element in v %}
        <h1>v value  is </h1>
        {{ element.Name }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```